# Laravel Trying To Unit Test API JSON Response

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

Trying to learn too many new things at once here (Laravel, PHPUnit, etc), so this is probably just a tired brain problem, would still appreciate some help.

I have a very basic 'Blog' project using Laravel as the API layer and AngularJS as the front end.  I want to unit test the API end-points but I am having trouble figuring out how to process JSON while in my test functions.

When I try to run testGetBlogPosts() I see what looks like the JSON output in my CLI, but I am unable to json_decode() and check that certain parts of the object match my expected result.  Here I simply want to make sure that the ID on the first object in the result array is ID "1".

The result I receive from the test is:
1) ExampleTest::testGetBlogPosts
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated!

**TL;DR: Test case is not correctly processing JSON response from API endpoint**

**Controller**

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */
    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

    public function getBlogPosts()
    {
        $posts = Post::get()->take(5)->toJson();
        // echo $posts; PER THE ACCEPTED ANSWER, RETURN NOT ECHO
        return $posts;
    }
    public function getSinglePost($postId)
    {
        $posts = Post::find($postId)->toJson();
        // echo $posts; PER THE ACCEPTED ANSWER, RETURN NOT ECHO
        return $posts;
    }

}
```

**Test File**

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }

    public function testGetBlogPosts()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'api/getBlogPosts');

        $array = json_decode($response);
        $result = false;
        if($array[0]->id == 1)
        {
            $result = true;
        }
        $this->assertEquals(true, $result);
    }
}
```

**As requested, the full test output**

> root@homestead:/home/vagrant/Laravel/Homestead/Blog# phpunit PHPUnit
>   3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from
>   /home/vagrant/Laravel/Homestead/Blog/phpunit.xml
>
> .E[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","title":"This is a test
>   post","post_body":"testststs","created_at":"2014-08-07
>   19:26:26","updated_at":"2014-08-07
>   19:26:26"},{"id":"2","user_id":"75","title":"Libero rerum rem
>   praesentium et et at doloribus asperiores.","post_body":"Commodi aut
>   beatae aut veritatis eum soluta sint. In aut cumque iure
>   quis.","created_at":"2014-08-07 19:26:26","updated_at":"2014-08-07
>   19:26:26"}]
>
> Time: 1.85 seconds, Memory: 18.50Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) ExampleTest::testGetBlogPosts ErrorException: Trying to get
>   property of non-object
>
> /home/vagrant/Laravel/Homestead/Blog/app/tests/ExampleTest.php:22
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 2, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.

**If I go to this endpoint in a browser I get this**

```
[
{
id: 1,
user_id: 1,
title: "This is a test post",
subtitle: "",
post_body: "testststs",
created_at: "2014-08-07 19:26:04",
updated_at: "2014-08-07 19:26:04"
},
{
id: 2,
user_id: 18,
title: "Rem deserunt dolor odit tempore qui eaque labore.",
subtitle: "",
post_body: "Ea a adipisci molestiae vel dignissimos. Ea blanditiis et est.",
created_at: "2014-08-07 19:26:04",
updated_at: "2014-08-07 19:26:04"
}
]
```

Comment: Can you paste the litteral `$response`?

Comment: is there any error that is occurring (undefined index, illegal offset, something along those lines)?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `$response->getContent()`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Thanks for responding!  I tried $response->getContent() in the json_decode() with the exact same result.

Comment: @watcher - I'm not seeing anything that looks like bad problems other than what I believe is the PHPUnit error.  Then again, not all that familiar with PHPUnit so I might be mis-reading the output.

Comment: Hmm, I figured the 'trying to get property of non-object' error was the result of `$array[0]->id` when `json_decode` had failed to decode `$response`.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't your controller return $posts instead of echoing it?

Comment: @don't panic - Make a response with that one--that was it!  Just needed to do a return instead of echo.  It's been a (derp) kind of day.

Comment: Try `$this->seeJson();` before `json_decode()`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getBlogPosts()` method in your controller echos `$post` rather than returning it.  This means that the `$response` in your test will not have anything in it to `json_decode`.

Answer (score 12):

Hope you figured it out by now but here is what I use:

`$array = json_decode($response->getContent());`

Comment: I specifically used `$this->response->getContent()`.

Comment: And for the status: $response->getStatusCode()

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `json` method directly off the response object.

```
$response = $this->getJson('/foo');
$json = $response->json(); // ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'boo']
```

It also accepts a key as an argument.

```
$foo = $response->json('foo'); // 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a method in `/tests/TestCase.php` helps a lot:

```
/**
 * dumps json result
 * @param string $function can be print_r, var_dump or var_export
 * @param boolean $json_decode 
 */
public function dump($function = 'var_export', $json_decode = true) {
    $content = $this->response->getContent();
    if ($json_decode) {
        $content = json_decode($content, true);
    }
    // ❤ ✓ ☀ ★ ☆ ☂ ♞ ☯ ☭ € ☎ ∞ ❄ ♫ ₽ ☼
    $seperator = '❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤';
    echo PHP_EOL . $seperator . PHP_EOL;
    $function($content);
    echo $seperator . PHP_EOL;
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can call it at any point after json call:

```
public function testInvalidPostID() {
    $this->json('PUT', '/posts/2222/sh-comments/1001', [
        'input' => 'SomeThing'
            ], [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . app('jwt')->getTokenForUser(2)
    ])->dump() //dumpnig output as array
      ->seeJsonStructure(['errors' => [
            '*' => [
                'message'
            ]
        ]
    ])->assertResponseStatus(404);
}
```